# DbContext error when scaffolding Identity in Blazor Server app

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I'm learning Blazor Server and have an app with an existing DbContext (EF/MSSQL) for CRUD operations.

Now I'd like to implement Identity and for that I'm following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=netcore-cli#scaffold-identity-into-a-blazor-server-project).
I'm on Visual Studio for Mac, so I use the CLI commands.

My error occurs when running this command:
`dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc MyApp.Data.Models.DBContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login"`

It says:

`DbContext type 'DBContext' is found but it does not inherit from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext'`

That's obviously true, but what then? Create another DbContext that inherits from  IdentityDbContext and use that instead?

The end result should be, that when I'm done with the migration part, the database tables for the Identity (users, roles and so on) are created in my existing database.

If you need some specific code parts from my app, please let me know.

Comment: `Create another DbContext that inherits from IdentityDbContext and use that instead?` Yes. A DbContext contains the entities needed for a specific use case. It's not a database model. ASP.NET Identity requires specific entities with specific mappings. Quite likely the authentication database won't even be the same as the application database. Multiple web apps may be using the *same* accounts. All those web apps would have to use a separate IdentityDbContext instead of copying the Identity entities to their own app contexts

Comment: Thanks. Now the step is completed. Should I then change the connectionstring to my current one? It suggest some localdb.

Comment: The answer was 'yes' :-)